# Simplest IMAP configuration without SSL

Tags: ubuntu, email, imap

I'm developing an email client and need a IMAP server without ssl to test with.

I have a bare Ubuntu 16.04 install with DigitalOceans I would like to setup as a simple imap server. It doesn't need to be able to accually send emails, I just need to be able to connect to it using the imap protocal.

What's the bare minimum configuration required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dovecot` should work more or less out of the box.  You may need to enable plaintext auth on insecure connections.  Uncomment the `disable_plaintext_auth` line and change `yes` to `no`

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
```

Install the package with the command `sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [guide](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/)

that set ups [this](http://www.courier-mta.org/imap/) email server

and use port **143** for the IMAP without SSH

Comment: This answer could be more useful if it included a summary of the important parts of your linked guide. It is likely possible to skip many steps, since the server is only to be used for testing IMAP communications

Answer (score 0):

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
```

Configure the protocol you need to be used by appending the protocol in the file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:

```
protocols = imap
```

Choose the mailbox you would like to use. Dovecot supports maildir and mbox formats. Edit the file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf and change the line

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir # (for maildir)
```

or

```
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/spool/mail/%u # (for mbox)
```

Restart the service:

```
systemctl restart dovecot
```

Use telnet to check that dovecot is working properly.

```
telnet localhost imap
```